# set_intersection on range of ranges

Tags: c++, range-v3

Why isn't it possible to do the following:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v1{{0,0}, {1,0}, {1,1}, {0,1}};
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v2{{1,0}, {2,0}, {2,1}, {1,1}};
auto p = ranges::set_intersection(v1,v2);
```

Where the result of p would be `{{1,0}, {1,1}}`. I suppose I am asking for matching subsets. It would be great if set_intersection took a custom predicate to provide this behavior. I can think of at least one way to do this using other ranges e.g.:

```
  auto equal = [](auto&& t){return ranges::equal(std::get<0>(t), std::get<1>(t));};

  auto matching_subsets = ranges::views::cartesian_product(v1,v2)
    | ranges::views::filter(equal)
    | ranges::views::transform([](auto&& t){return std::get<0>(t);});
```

I am picturing something like:

```
auto p = ranges::set_intersection(v1, v2, ranges::equal);
```

Comment: What about std::set_intersection?

Comment: The rangesv3 set_intersection takes a predicate

Answer (score 1):

We can use `std::set_intersection` (as jrok mentioned in the comments) and do the following,

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v1{{0,0}, {1,0}, {1,1}, {0,1}};
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v2{{1,0}, {2,0}, {2,1}, {1,1}};
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v_intersection;

std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                      v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                      std::back_inserter(v_intersection));
for(const auto& v : v_intersection){
    for(const auto& n : v){
        cout<<n<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Output

```
1 0 
1 1
```

Note that, the two input ranges has to be sorted for this to work.

Comment: [`set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) requires sorted ranges.